# .collectionBehavior not putting NSWindow on all Mac spaces

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI project and I'm trying to create a window in the corner that will show up over every other application on all spaces. I've assigned a custom AppDelegate to my `@main` struct, and on `.applicationDidFinishLaunching()`, I'm running the function `onPanelOpen()` below. To observe, run the code below and switch spaces, and the green window will not follow show in any space besides the one you run it in.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct LyriXApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("LyriX Overlay", id: "lyrix-overlay") {
            EmptyView()
                .overlay {
                    Text("LyriX App")
                        .frame(width: 500, height: 100)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    onPanelOpen()
                }
        }
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact)
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    }
}

func onPanelOpen() {
    if let window = NSApp.windows.first {
        guard window.title == "LyriX Overlay" else {
            return
        }
        //hide buttons
        window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        
        //hide title and bar
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        window.level = .floating
        window.styleMask = [.fullSizeContentView, .borderless, .utilityWindow, .nonactivatingPanel]
        window.titlebarSeparatorStyle = .none
        window.isOpaque = false
        window.backgroundColor = .green
        window.collectionBehavior = [.stationary, .canJoinAllSpaces]
        window.animationBehavior = .utilityWindow
        
        
        // set width and height to 500x100
        window.maxSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 100)
        window.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 100), display: true);
        window.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: (NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.maxX)! - 520, y: (NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.maxY)! - 120))
        
        window.orderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

However, the window isn't actually showing up on every space when I switch spaces. I'm happy to take any advice on what I could be doing wrong or differently. Running this on Xcode 15.2 on Sonoma 14.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `styleMask` conflicts with the behavior that you want. Specifically, it looks like `.titled` causes the problem.

So, you can either:

```
window.styleMask.remove(.titled)
```

Or, specifically set the mask you want:

```
window.styleMask = [.fullSizeContentView, .borderless, .utilityWindow, .nonactivatingPanel]
```

Note that either solution ends up without the rounded corners you have now. You can, though, just handle that at your view level.

---

Edit to address new information in comments:

```
@main
struct LyriXApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("LyriX Overlay", id: "lyrix-overlay") {
            Text("LyriX App")
                .frame(width: 500, height: 100)
                .task {
                    onPanelOpen()
                }
        }
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact)
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does .titled have to do with the spaces the window appears in? Removing it doesn't seem to change the behavior for me

Comment: Did you try the second code block?

Comment: Yep, neither make a difference

Comment: I just ran it again and it is working for me. Are you running just the minimal sample that you provided, plus my change (ie remove all of your styleMask lines and replace with mine)?

Comment: Alright, going back to the minimal sample, it does seem to work, but two things that I'm using in the actual code base are still causing problems. I've just edited the sample code to include these two, an overlay above an empty view instead of a root view to ignore the title bar safe area of NSWindows as well as running the onPanelOpen in an onAppear handler rather than an app delegate (due to state management reasons in the main codebase)

Comment: I'm not clear what the `EmptyView` `overlay` thing is, but I suggest you address that in a different question with examples of what it looks like with/without that. I'm guessing using something like `ignoresSafeArea` will solve that. Ignoring that I've put an update on my post to show a solution to the onAppear issue.